# shutdown.exe parameters with dashes or slashes?

Tags: windows

I use a call of `shutdown.exe` to reboot machines having different versions of Windows installed.

For Windows XP the command is:

```
shutdown.exe -r -f -t 01
```

For other versions of Windows I use:

```
shutdown.exe /L /R /C /Y /T:1
```

Now it seems, that the second command won't work on Windows XP. Does anybody know which versions of Windows support slashes and which dashes?

EDIT:

This is not an issue of wrong parameters. Here is a printout from an affected machine (German installation of Windows XP):

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\shutdown.exe /L /R /C /Y /T:1
Syntax: shutdown.exe [-l | -s | -r | -a] [-f] [-m \\Computer] [-t xx]
             [-c "Kommentar"] [-d up:xx:yy]

....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on both XPSP3 and Win7

`shutdown.exe -r -f -t 0` and `shutdown.exe /r /f /t 0` appear to be functionally identical, either dash or slash will work.

Neither XP/7 (US-en) lists the "Y" switch as an option however.  Could this be your problem, or is this a feature of the the localized implementation of `shutdown`?

Edit:

Additional testing suggests that logoff `/L` and restart `/R` are mutually exclusive options.

Comment: I think that the '/Y' parameter was introduced because on some machines under NT a proprietary shutdown.exe was used, which featured this parameter.